# When UPDATE the TABLE using python and sqlite ,, I am getting this error --Incorrect number of bindings supplied

Tags: python-3.x

I  am getting this error --

> Incorrect number of bindings supplied The current statement uses 4,
>   and there are 3 supplied.

Here is the code --

```
def update_entry(self):
     self.cur.execute('UPDATE SINGLE SET IN=?,OUT=?,QUALITY=? WHERE ID=?',
 (self.IN_entry.get(),self.OUT_entry.get(),self.QC_entry.get()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 4 placeholders in your query and yet you're supplying only 3 items in the tuple passed to `execute`. You should supply a value for the placeholder for `ID` as the 4th item in the tuple.